# Grails 3.1.9 : POST not recognized

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I'm using Grails 3.1.9 with the `rest-api` profile. 
After creating models and controllers (by grails CLI) and started the application.
I cannot create POST by Postman/Curl etc..

If I try to call the save method directly, eg:

```
http://localhost:8080/mymodel/create
```

All works fine. But if I try to call it by POST, the method save() will never be called (index is the default action).

p.s. I have this on my controller:

```
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
```

Why this happens?

Comment: A workaround is possible, filtering by params.getRequest().getMethod() but...

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke `save()` method by POST, not `create()` which is usually used just to show form view of created element. So instead executing

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"foo":"bar"}' http://localhost:8080/mymodel/create
```

use:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"foo":"bar"}' http://localhost:8080/mymodel/save
```

---

Of course if you used url mapping properly instead of `http://localhost:8080/mymodel/save` you should use simple `http://localhost:8080/mymodel`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I made a mistake in my request. I call save() not create().

Answer (score 0):

Sure that this is a bug, I open an issue on github. Closed like *not a bug*.

I forgot to add on `UrlMappings.groovy` the following line:

```
  "/foos"(resources:"foo")
```

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10067